# collecting reaction times from inside a docker container

Tags: python, docker

I develop python application for use in neuroscience and psychological research.  These applications mostly present visual information and/or sounds and require input from the user (experiment subjects). Because of this, I need to solve two specific problems.  First - applications frequently need to be distributed to many users, with different environments and operating systems.  This is a big headache for me, because the people receiving the applications aren't necessarily very "tech savvy", so I end up spending a lot of time troubleshooting small issues.  Second - because these applications are required for research, I need for them to be completely backwards compatible (like, 20 years later, compatible).  This is because there are occasionally times that we need to re-run experiments from the past, or revisit some things we have done.

I've been playing around with docker lately,and I'm feeling like this might be the answer to my problems (and maybe for a lot of academics).  If I could containerize my applications, with environments set up with specific versions of specific packages, I would be able to send them to anyone (which they could run from the container), and re-run things from the past in their original containers.

I feel like I'm getting conflicting information about the utility of docker for non-web (desktop) applications.  Is there any reason this wouldn't work? Often I collect time sensitive input (like reaction time) - would running applications inside the docker (and somehow sharing the screen) substantially alter reaction time data?  Would I lose the millisecond precision I am going for?  Is this not really what docker is intended for?

Comment: There is an overhead. What you need to know for your application is ? Does that overhead is in acceptable margin. Does changing kernel or docker version modify that overhead in a way that can affect measurement. Sadly, i don't have any number for input reaction time. if you find some i would be really interested by the result.

Comment: Thanks, Regan.  I would also be interested to know this.  If the container stayed relatively stable, you might imagine that you'd just have a set amount of noise distributed across all of your reaction times, which wouldn't be so terrible.  As you mention, though, it would be way better to know what that noise is...

Comment: Testing the noise shouldn't be a hard task. As long as your computer isn't busy with resource consuming task, the container will remain stable. Testing the part of your application that acquire the reaction time of the user inside and outside a container shouldn't be a hard task. I think (personal opinion) that the noise should be non relevant but it need to be tested to be sure